# How to display a bar category on the axis when the value is 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a dataframe column with the category of the corresponding row blood pressure systolic and diastolic values as obtained by the following function:

```
def classify_bp(row):
    if row.SYS < 120 and row.DIA < 80:
        return "normal"
    elif (row.SYS >= 120 and row.SYS <= 129) and row.DIA < 80:
        return "elevated"
    elif (row.SYS >= 130 and row.SYS <= 139) or (row.DIA >= 80 and row.DIA <= 89):
        return "stage1"
    elif (row.SYS >= 140 and row.SYS <= 179) or (row.DIA >= 90 and row.DIA <= 119):
        return "stage2"
    elif row.SYS > 180 or row.DIA > 120:
        return "crisis"
```

If I apply this function to the blood pressure readings dataframe I can generate a new df column called `"bp_class"` with the proper blood pressure reading categorization for each row.

If I apply the `value_counts()` function to that column I obtain the following:

```
df_simple["bp_class"].value_counts(sort=False)
normal      37
stage1      34
elevated    15
```

I would like to produce a seaborn barchart with the 5 categories on the x axis, possibly always in the same order of the function (normal, elevated,stage1,stage2,crisis) and the frequencies for each including the categories with zero observations (which are not known to the `value_counts()` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.Series.reindex) with a list of all possible categories:

```
# your sample data
s = pd.Series(index=['normal', 'stage1', 'elevated'], data=[37, 34, 15], name='bp_class')

plot_data = s.reindex(['normal', 'elevated', 'stage1', 'stage2', 'crisis'])
sns.barplot(x=plot_data.index, y=plot_data.values)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just reindex without combine_first?

Comment: @creanion oops, good point. will update the anser. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you works well and also gives me something to better understand :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you have a categorical dtype seaborn will extend the categorical axis without further action. Here using an index to assign index-data relation but then resetting the index to get the data in long format suitable for seaborn plots.

```
class_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['normal', 'elevated', 'stage1', 'stage2', 'crisis'], ordered=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(['normal', 'stage1', 'elevated'], dtype=class_cat),
                  data={"bp_class": [37, 34, 15]}).reset_index()

sns.barplot(data=df, x="index", y="bp_class")
```

This as sidenote to Stef's answer.

[image]

---

If you start from

```
counts = df_simple["bp_class"].value_counts(sort=False).to_frame()
```

Then we'd transform the index from there instead:

```
df = counts.set_axis(counts.index.astype(class_cat)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Also thanks a lot. I still need to understand some of the magic of the previous solution so am not able to decide which is better yet. Take care.